# getTag method in fragment return null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to use FragmentActivity with single Fragment without viewpager and others.

I need the tag value from Fragment with the getTag method...

My code in onCreate of FragmentActivity :

```
    // launch splash screen fragment
    Fragment fragment = SplashScreenFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content,          fragment).commit();
```

And when SplashScreenFragment is onCreateView, getTag() method return null in fragment..

I don't understand this .. I don't use Fragment attribut in XML layout, that is a reason ?

EDIT ::

I need tag to execute this code :

```
    this.mSplashScreenFragment = (SplashScreenFragment) mMainFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

mSplashScreenFragment after this line is null ..

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ability to access fragment tag you should use

```
FragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

method when you want to add fragment. In other words you should first set this tag from anywhere

Comment: Thanks !

The tag value in Fragment is now this i've setted in FragmentActivity previously, but i have the same problem with this code : 

  this.mSplashScreenFragment = (SplashScreenFragment) mMainFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag); 

mSplashScreenFragment after this line, is null with my customize tag ... any idea ?

Comment: If you trying to find fragment immediately after calling "getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(..." - you shouldn't get it working because of fragment transaction runs asynchronously. Try to do this in Activity.onResume method